# Separate ViewModels for same ListFragment and DetailsFragment or Same Viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I read somewhere that google recommends that every fragment that you have in your project should have its own `ViewModel`.

But...

Let's suppose you have the same set of data being passed in both the Fragments, for instance, i have a `MovieListFragment` and a `MovieDetailsFragment`, so now i am wondering if i should make Separate ViewModels for these or should i go for Same Viewmodel?

I want to understand which would be the better approach here.

Comment: It sounds like you actually need a [data layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer) that both separate ViewModels get their data from.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have that data layer but i am confused that for these 2 fragments, should i make only one Viewmodel or should i go for separate viewmodels for both of them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared view model has shown in the Android code lab. The whole idea with a view model is to share. But if you don't have to share between fragments but only return data to activity then you should have one view model per fragment.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0